how to print block like characters in unix
How can I make "▒" in unix shell script like this --> 

You want to be able to print something like above?
You can simply use:
echo "11▒"

or
export LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
echo -e "11\u2592"

export LANG=en_GB.UTF-8 because as user1934428 said:

Perhaps it should be added, that LANG should be set to some utf8 value, for instance en_GB.UTF-8

To ensure that the Unicode character is correctly displayed, the LANG environment variable should be set to a UTF-8 locale.
-e stands for the interpretation of backslash escape sequences
\u2592 is the Unicode code for the character “▒”.

Perhaps it should be added, that LANG should be set to some utf8 value, for instance en_GB.UTF-8.

You're absolutely right. To ensure, I quoted your comment and added the export.
